# debian mount windows share in linux and share it with samba without password

Tags: debian, samba

I would like to know how I would properly mount my windows harddrives in my VM ( debian ) and share it with samba so that other users can access it without a password.

I'm going this way because I would like to access the folders on my mediacenter and with windows i had no luck at all to get this to work, now I've got it working but it keeps asking me for a username and password which is very anoying.

in /etc/fstab I wrote:

```
//192.168.0.1/e /mnt/e cifs username=mywinuser,password=xxx,dmask=777,fmask=777,uid=mylinuxuser,guid=mylinuxuser,rw
```

in  /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[tv]
  browseable = yes
  path = /mnt/e/TV
  guest ok = yes
  read only = yes
  create mask = 0700
```

in my smb.conf I tried setting

```
security = share 
user = nobody
```

but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and didn't have to mess with the Samba conf. Here's my fstab line if it helps:

```
//192.168.0.150/z  /media/z  cifs  username=###,password=###  0 0
```

According to some documentation I read, the mask flags are only necessary if you're super concerned about the permissions your Linux box sees on the CIFS share. I'm not (and run as root, it's a test VM), so I omitted them and it works fine.

Maybe you should try resetting your Samba configs to their defaults and using the simpler fstab line?